# Create external Hadoop table with escape char

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

a want to create an external hadoop table that will take data from another table which have in one of the columns string with \n character.

How should i create this table to include \n in my hadoop/hive table?

Answer (score 1):

Use escaped \n i.e.`\\N` to identify \n as nulls in Hive